# How to improve performance for condition "or" in C#

Tags: c#

I have a if statement

```
 DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(assign.Start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
 DateTime finish = Convert.ToDateTime(assign.Finish.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
 DateTime pic1 = Convert.ToDateTime(re.timepicker1().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
 DateTime pic2 = Convert.ToDateTime(re.timepicker2().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
 if (start == pic1 || start < pic1 && finish >= pic1  || start > pic1 && finish <= pic2 || start > pic1 && start < pic2)
```

So, how to increases performance do it? Now, It runs slowly.

Comment: Please paste your list array.

Comment: One straightforward way would be to call `Convert.ToDateTime` only once for each value…

Comment: Thanks all, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Converting string to datetime is quite a demanding task, you should do it only when it's necessary. Also, when you know that you'll require the same DateTime values, store the results of previous convertions and use them later, so you will not have to convert values again.

In your code you have DateTime values, then you convert them to string, and then you convert them back to DateTime. Why not compare the original DareTime values?

If you want to use date information only and skip time, property Date is there for you:

```
var dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
var dateToday = datetimeNow.Date;
```

Compare values from property .Date, then you will not need any string conversions.

Comment: Thanks Michal@@ i understood :)

Comment: My purpose is cut time in datetime but I update my question :)

Comment: @gggg I see, I updated my answer to show you how to get date value from datetime without converting it to string, if you think it's helpful, then please mark my answer as accepted :) Good luck!